# Get a reference to DOM element that is not child of the component

Tags: angular, viewchild

In angular, ViewChild is used to gain a reference to dom element that is placed inside of the HTML file for particular component. How can I get a reference to the DOM element that lives outside of components HTML file? For example, it lives in grandparents sibling component.

Comment: What's your use case ? Looks like against the component philosophy. I would recommand using EventEmitter on the child component, and let that grandparent sibling of yours handle his DOM element accordingly.

Comment: It could be to get info on a overlay/dialog for example which sites outside the main content of the app